# Using both AND and OR Filtering options - Material UI DataGrid/XGrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a big table of data and have created some Select components to show all of the unique options in that column.

If my data was about supermarkets, I want to be able to see all in America. So America is selected and it works well so far. Then I want to see all Supermarkets that stock Bananas in America, so from the location column America is selected, and in the fruits, column bananas are selected. Still working well.

If I want to see all Supermarkets in America that stock Bananas or Apples, we get problems.

How can I apply the `AND` to separate columns, but the `OR` to filters of the same column?

Comment: Have you tried multi-column filtering? https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/filtering/#multi-column-filtering

Comment: I have. That's what I'm wanting to use. What I want is to be able to use both the linkOperator: GridLinkOperator.Or, as well as linkOperator: GridLinkOperator.And, in different situations

Comment: Based on implementation, you are able to apply an operator to selected filter items.

Comment: Same problem here. Looking for a way to select multiple values from the GUI  in in singleSelect columns filter  and a filter like unsing  JS `includes()` for that columns values only.

Comment: Yeap, same here. We are using the Data Grid pro and we need to be able to combine ANDs and ORs while filtering. Here is an example of the filter we need:
Person name is John AND Person height is more than 6 feet AND (dob is empty OR dob is before 1/1/1990). This seems to be impossible at this time

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to use 2 different link operators, you can achieve what you need using the right combination of filter operator and link operator.

There's no way to do that using the default filter panel. You'll have to create and manually [pass a filter model to the grid](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/#pass-filters-to-the-grid).

Steps to get it done:

1. Use the `isAnyOf` filter operator.
2. Provide the filter value as an array of values.
3. Use the `AND` link operator.
4. Manually pass the custom filter model created to the grid.

Note:
Your UI should contain some sort of dropdowns for each column with multiple checkboxes for all the choices that can be added to the filter value array.
So in your case, a dropdown for countries, and another for fruits.

The filter Model should look something like this:

[image: With]